# AudioKit: How can I change the volume or pitch of a note played with AKMIDIEvent?

Tags: ios, swift, midi, audiokit

Using AudioKit I am playing a note using

```
midi.sendEvent(AKMIDIEvent(noteOff: noteToPlay, velocity: MIDIVelocity(0), channel: MIDIChannel(0)))
```

Is there a command that I can use to change to volume or pitch of that played note using AudioKit?

Comment: I think soo you need to controller the volume through the oscillator. -- let oscillator = AKOscillator() -- and control it through -- oscillator.amplitude = 0.5 -- The amplitude, with a scale from 0 to 1, gives the volume.

Comment: You have to send controller change events.

Comment: can you give me a working example @CL.  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some search, I found the indeed that the controller change events that CL has mentioned do the job.

So taking into account that the commands are

```
/// Modulation Control
case modulationWheel = 1
/// Breath Control (in MIDI Saxophones for example)
case breathControl = 2
/// Foot Control
case footControl = 4
/// Portamento effect
case portamento = 5
/// Data Entry
case dataEntry = 6
/// Volume (Overall)
case mainVolume = 7
/// Balance
case balance = 8
/// Stereo Panning
case pan = 10
/// Expression Pedal
case expression = 11
```

I need to call

```
midi.sendEvent(AKMIDIEvent(controllerChange: 7, value: MIDIByte(volume), channel: MIDIChannel(0)))
```